# c++ additional parameters on RegCreateKeyEx to protect registry key

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I want to ask, how to open registry key to protect it. As I read I should use `RegCreateKeyEx` instead of `RegOpenKeyEx` but how that open should look like, that other processes couldn't delete it.

I used to use:

```
long lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"TypeLib\\{0971C3C0-FEA6-49BA-AFEA-7C898DBE175B}\\9.0\\HELPDIR", NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
```

How should I rewrite it, to make registry protected.

Comment: What do you mean by "protect"? Do you want to prevent people modifying/deleting it just while you have it open, or do you want to prevent modifications/deletions in the future too?

Comment: @Ben If there is a possibility I would like to know how to make both things, but I've been thinking about first-one, protect it while it is opened.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Generally you cannot prevent someone with the same login and security rights as you from doing anything you can do. This is by design. Probably if you tell us what you are trying to achieve we can help more.

Comment: @Ben Now I'm developing registry cleaner and I need to make such a situation for testing purposes. Probably `RedDeleteKeyEx` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if someone is using that key. However from QA I got message about a bug and not sure what exactly is wrong, there might be few places from where that bug comes, one of them is protected registry.

Comment: @ST3: It sounds like you're in over your head. Your "registry cleaner" might be causing more problems than it solves, and they certainly will be harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I agree with MSalters above. I would suggest being very careful indeed with deleting registry keys which you did not put there in the first place. Deleting entries for random typelibs is not necessarily a good idea unless you are *certain* they are not wanted - e.g. if they belong to the Potentially Unwanted Software you are trying to remove.

You want to prevent your software from deleting a key in order to reproduce a bug, and allow your software to continue it's job. ***However there are (at least) three possible causes***, so you need to make sure your registry cleaner can handle ***all*** of them appropriately.

**What might prevent deletion of a registry key**

**Is the key still open?**

Firstly (and most likely), a key cannot be deleted while any handle to it is open. This is by design and in the documentation.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724845(v=vs.85).aspx

However you can delete all values of the key, delete subkeys which are not themselves open, and so on.

Also be aware that you cannot delete a key which you have open yourself, so make sure you don't have an open handle yourself.

You can use SysInternals process explorer to determine whether your process, or any other process, has the registry key open.

**Do you have permission?**

Secondly, you should check you have permission to delete the key. Permissions can be set so that nobody can do particular actions or any action at all, including change permission. The exception is that the owner can always change the permissions, and administrators can change the owner to themselves.

So if you do not have permission to delete the key, and are not the owner, then you will need the "Take Ownership" privilege. You can then take ownership, change the permissions to allow you to delete the key, and then delete it. Administrators usually have the "Take Ownership" privilege.

You can examine the permissions of a registry key using RegEdit.exe - provided you have permission to view the permissions of course!

**Is the action blocked by security software?**

Finally any action in the system can be vetoed by security software such as Anti-Virus programs. This will also manifest itself as an Access Denied error.

**How to prevent deletion of a registry key**

Therefore to prevent deletion of a registry key you can:

- Create a process which opens the key and keeps it open.
- Change permission to deny the delete permission to all users.
- Install a device driver which intercepts registry calls (for example using detours) and does not allow deletion of the key.